# Does noscript content load in bg

Tags: html, noscript

Does the html tag noscript load the content in the background, even when javascript is enabled?

I have a random image that is called by JS each time the pageloads, but I would like all of the links (not just the current random one) to be crawled.  At the same time, I don't want the pageload to slow down because images are loading in the background like they do with display:none.  I also want to call these images and links in the html because of CMS reference issues with Javascript.

Answer (score 6):

Image references in NOSCRIPT tags are not loaded at all when Javascript is enabled.

You can test this my making a number of large images, putting them inside the NOSCRIPT tag and watching browser activity.

Comment: Are you sure that is true in *every* browser?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes : IE6, IE7, Opera, Firefox, Chrome and Safari. `noscript` has other issues, but the no-loading policy is consistent

Comment: Firefox 7 (and according to the web also before 4) _does_ load images in noscript tags even when JavaScript is enabled. Just for the record. I just ran into this bug.

Comment: I've learned why: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=342299 It only happens in XHTML mode. In HTML mode, it works as one could expect it.